# How can I add the array to the array of arrays in SQL (Postgres)

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table with an attribute that is an array of arrays.

Example: `a={{1,A, 1},{A,B,C},{45,46,47}}`

I want to add an array to the array "a".

Example: `new_array={Z,T}` to "a" in order to have `a={{Z,T},{1,A, 1},{A,B,C},{45,46,47}}` `

I used the command: `update test set a = ARRAY['Z','T'] || a`;

but I got this error: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

So, I tried to add the `::text[]` parameter in this way:
`update test set a = ARRAY['Z','T']::text[] || a::text[];`

but there is still an error:

```
ERROR:  cannot concatenate incompatible arrays
DETAIL:  Arrays with differing dimensions are not compatible for concatenation.
```

Hence, my question is: how can I add the array to the array of arrays?
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make them the same dimention add a null:

```
select '{{1,A, 1},{A,B,C},{45,46,47}}'::text[] || '{Z, T, null}';
                ?column?                 
-----------------------------------------
 {{1,A,1},{A,B,C},{45,46,47},{Z,T,NULL}}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I need different dimension. Is it possible to have it?

Comment: @DarkCoffee No, Pg arrays need to be symmetric across the dimensions. They're not arrays of arrays, they are actual multidimensional arrays - think "like a matrix". They can't be sparse or short. It's to do with how the memory for them is managed internally and how they are accessed.